# How do I get the div contained in the div table cells to fill?

Tags: css

I'm trying to get the divs that are contained within the table cell divs (contained in the code sandbox below) to expand and fill their parent div without it overlapping the next cell below it

https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-water-k5qb8

I've added a grey border around the areas which I want to fill the cells. I've tried playing around with the css but nothing seems to work 100% correctly

Here's the code for the div:-

```
    <div
        tabIndex={-1}
        contentEditable
        id={id}
        title={value}
        style={{
            border: '1px',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
            borderColor: 'grey',
            textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        }}>
        {value}
    </div>
```

And the code for the table cell that contains it:-

```
            <TableCell
                component="div"
                variant="body"
                key={key}
                padding="none"
                style={{
                    width: `${currentColWidth}px`,
                    display: 'inline-block'
                }}
                className={clsx(classes.tableCell)}
                onClick={handleCellClick}>
                <DataTableField id={key} column={column} value={value} focusedId={focusedId} />
            </TableCell>
```

And a screenshot that shows the bordered div not growing to fill it's parent:-

[image: screenshot]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code (not just a link out to the code).

Comment: It's difficult to illustrate with just a single piece of code (hence why I attached it as a sandbox) but I'll try

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the header line of the table, just add `&nbsp;` instead of space . For example instead of Calories (g)  --> `Calories&nbsp;(g)`

Comment: No I mean the actual data held in the cells. I'll try and attach a screenshot

Comment: You should give a specific width in the first square in each row. try this <td width="200px;"></td>

Comment: It's not the width that's the problem but the height

Comment: If you give width it will have more space to print the name so height will not be a problem. Otherwise try to give specific height in the td